# Handling Azure Logic app Action outputs

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

From my logic app, I'm calling an API-1. I need to pass this output as input to API-2.

I used this @body('[My_Action_Name]') and @{body('[Action_Name]')}. But it's just returned as a output to my API-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are authoring your logic app directly in code view, then the correct syntax is just @body('actionName')

As an example take a look at the below

```
    "HttpAction1": {
        "type": "Http",
        "inputs": {
            "method": "GET",
            "uri": "http://www.example.com"
        }
    },
    "HttpAction2": {
        "type": "Http",
        "inputs": {
            "body": "@body('HttpAction1')",
            "method": "POST",
            "uri": "http://www.example2.com"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a follow up question.  What if I don't know the structure of the response from HttpAction1 yet and I want to use LogicApps to help me uncover that.  Is there a way to get all of the outputs of a previous action?

Comment: @Paul, you can always inspect the outputs of an action after it has completed (if you navigate to the logic app in azure portal, select any run -> select the action -> select action outputs) to review what properties are available. The logic apps designer also has a first-class authoring support for APIs described by publicly accessible swagger (use the http + swagger operation)